# Set Padding on Minimum Width [Aura]

Tags: lightning, css

I'd like to add SLDS padding for a minimum width value of an input field. Have the padding set in my code, I just need it to only display when the width of the screen is larger than 760px

.cmp

```
    <div class="minimumWidth">
      <lightning:input class=" slds-size_1-of-1 slds-medium-size--1-of-2 slds-large-size--1-of-2 "
       name="field1" label="field1" required="true" aura:id="field1" />
   </div>
```

.css

```
.THIS .minimumWidth .slds-p-left_medium{min-width:760px;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your markup, You can use slds classes. For padding you need to add `slds-p-around_x-small` class in your div tag.

```
<div class="minimumWidth slds-p-around_x-small">
      <lightning:input class=" slds-size_1-of-1 slds-medium-size--1-of-2 slds-large-size--1-of-2 "
       name="field1" label="field1" required="true" aura:id="field1" />
   </div>
```

Refer https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/padding/  for slds classes for padding.

Comment: Thank you but I have the padding set in my code, I just need it to only display when the width of the screen is larger than 760px

Comment: You can use lightning layout & lightning layout items & set the different size for small, medium & large devices... https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:layout/example